# .length on array crashing when length is 1 (maybe issue with split)

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, split, string-length

I'm having trouble with this code.  I've tried to troubleshoot it many times and seem to have isolated the issue, but can't figure out the cause.

If the variable called string is set to something in the form of "text v. text," the code runs fine and the first if-statement triggers the sentence.  If the string contains text but no "v." i.e. nothing that meets the search separator value, the function fails and does not execute the second if-statement.

Link to Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qsq4we99/

Snippet of code, there also would need to be a html div with ID "outputtext."

```
function brokenCode()
    { 
    //Setting Relevant Variables
        var string = "red";
        var array = string.split("v.");
        var number = array.length;
    // Checking location of things
        var findText1 = array[0].search("search text");
        var findText2 = array[1].search("search text");
    //Running Conditional Stuff
        if(number > 1)
            {
            document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = "2+ listed";
            }
        else if(number < 2)
            {
            document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = "1 listed";
            }
    }                   
brokenCode();
```

In this simplified example there is no clear explanation why the search operations need to occur (they are there because in the real code they are needed... but something about them seems to be causing the problem (even in this simple example). If the two searches are removed, the code runs smoothly.

Comment: `array[1].search("search text");` If there's only one item in `array`, then index `1` will be non existent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't start setting variables from the array without checking for length. Before setting `findText1` & `findText2`, check to make sure the length of the array is greater than zero.

```
function brokenCode() { 
    //Setting Relevant Variables
    var string = "red";
    var array = string.split("v.");
    var number = array.length;

    if (number > 0) {
        // Checking location of things
        var findText1 = array[0].search("search text");
        var findText2 = array[1].search("search text");
        //Running Conditional Stuff
        if(number > 1)
        {
            document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = "2+ listed";
        }
        else if(number < 2)
        {
            document.getElementById('outputtext').innerHTML = "1 listed";
        }
   }        
}           
brokenCode();
```

Comment: He's accessing index 1, so the test will need to be `number > 1`